# VS2010 stucks for at least 10 seconds after change has been saved in App_Code directory

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Visual Studio 2010, with SP1 installed.

I have a ASP.Net(.Net4.0) website in development,  and there are a series of *.cs files in App_Code directory.

I understand all these code files are compiled by Just-In-Time compiler, but everything when I save the changes in these files, my VS2010 hangs, lasts for at least 10 seconds.
And I can do nothing while waiting for it to come back.

I try to use IIS to host the web site,  but the problem does not disappear.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: I would suggest looking for a beefier box. I did that at the office and it made my experience much more usable.